# Is there a jQuery/JavaScript function to adjust a range of <0 to 500> to <0 to 1>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the effect of jQuery Slider by using the position of the pointer over a `div`.
The range I get back is from `0 to 500` and would like to adjust this to `0 to 1` for the `opacity`
Is there any jQuery function to adjust ranges like this?

```
$('#old').mousemove( function(e){
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var mouseX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var mouseY = 500-(e.pageY - parentOffset.top);
    $('#position').html(mouseX+" "+mouseY);
    $('#old').css('opacity', '.'+mouseY);
});
```

`'.'+mouseY` the decimal is just there to get some result working.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/DdsRq/

Comment: Yeah, sure. I remember there was DivideBy500-jquery.js plugin.

Comment: @chrisloughnane, it's that or you are too comfortable with SO

Comment: Nope, I usually spend quite a while searching for answers and so often I don't post any questions as I figure it out. I had divided by 500 earlier but had not taken into account I had adjusted how the offset was calculated.

Comment: editing your title like that isn't helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply divide the returned value by 500 to get it to a value between 0 and 1.

```
$('#old').css('opacity', (mouseY/500));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdsRq/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply divide by 500. Then the maximum would be `500 / 500 === 1` and the minimum `0 / 500 === 0`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the percent of the value from 0 - 500?

```
var x = mouseY / 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the number by `500`:

```
$('#old').css('opacity', mouseY/500);
```

(All numbers in JavaScript are floating point - if you're worried about integer truncation, there's no need.)

Answer (score 0):

So hope this is what you expected
updated your jsfiddle ;)

```
$('#old').mousemove( function(e){
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    //mouseX = e.pageX;
    //mouseY = e.pageY;
    var mouseX = ((e.pageX - parentOffset.left) / $('#old').width());
    var mouseY = ((e.pageY - parentOffset.top) / $('#old').height());
    //mouseX = Math.round( mouseX * 10 ) / 10;

    $('#position').html(mouseX+" "+mouseY);
    $('#old').css('opacity', mouseY);
    $('#new').css('opacity', mouseX);


});

$('#old').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: '1.0'}, 1000);
});
```